# Fetch specific column in Django using JsonResponse

Tags: javascript, python, django, jsonresponse

I have a problem on how can I filter specific column using Jsonresponse in html. I just want to filter specific column  `Paid_by`. It is possible to filter in Jsonresponse just like this `response.data.paid_by`. Other option how to filter specific column in my `views` It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance.

*I tried `response.datas.paid_by`* but it returns undefined

*Views.py*

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    desc = cursor.description
    return[
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

def sample():
    blank = ""
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM app_person WHERE paid_by != %s GROUP BY paid_by, paid, category, category_status ORDER BY paid_by,paid", [blank])
         row = dictfetchall(cursor)
result = {'data':row}
return JsonResponse(result)
```

*JsonResponse Success html*

```
success: function(response){
    console.log(response.data) #fetch all data
    console.log(response.data.paid_by) #Undefined

    $("#rports").modal('show');
    $("#rports").val(null).trigger("change");
  }
```

Comment: Your structure returns multiple rows in an array and not only one

Comment: @klinac thanks for your response, but what can you recommend?

Comment: loop through response?

Comment: @iklinac  yes it loops through response, but if there's no yet solution do you have idea on how to filter specific column in my views?